# How to get the values out NumberPickerDialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

Im using a class to handle NumberPicker and I want to set the text of a Button with the values  from the Class. Im using six numberspicker in a NumberPickerDialog.

This is the class:

```
public class NumberPickerDialog extends AlertDialog implements OnClickListener {
private OnNumberSetListener mListener;
private NumberPicker mNumberPicker1;
private NumberPicker mNumberPicker2;
private NumberPicker mNumberPicker3;
private NumberPicker mNumberPicker4;
private NumberPicker mNumberPicker5;
private NumberPicker mNumberPicker6;

int n1; 
int n2; 
int n3; 
int n4;
int n5;
int n6;

private int mInitialValue;

public NumberPickerDialog(Context context, int theme, int initialValue) {
    super(context, theme);
    mInitialValue = initialValue;

    setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Confirmar", this);        
    setTitle("Valor Atual do Hodômetro (em Km)");

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sixnumber, null);
    setView(view);

    mNumberPicker1 = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.num_picker1);
    mNumberPicker2 = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.num_picker2);
    mNumberPicker3 = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.num_picker3);
    mNumberPicker4 = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.num_picker4);
    mNumberPicker5 = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.num_picker5);
    mNumberPicker6 = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.num_picker6);

}

/**
 * Retrieve the number picker used in the dialog
 */    
public NumberPicker getmNumberPicker1() {
    return mNumberPicker1;
}

public NumberPicker getmNumberPicker2() {
    return mNumberPicker2;
}

public NumberPicker getmNumberPicker3() {
    return mNumberPicker3;
}

public NumberPicker getmNumberPicker4() {
    return mNumberPicker4;
}

public NumberPicker getmNumberPicker5() {
    return mNumberPicker5;
}

public NumberPicker getmNumberPicker6() {
    return mNumberPicker6;
}

/**
 * Set the range allowed for the number picker
 * @param start the minimum allowed value
 * @param end the maximum allowed value     * 
 * and setting the value directly.
 */

public void setRange1(int start, int end) {
    mNumberPicker1.setRange(start, end);

}

public void setRange2(int start, int end) {
    mNumberPicker2.setRange(start, end);

}

public void setRange3(int start, int end) {
    mNumberPicker3.setRange(start, end);

}

public void setRange4(int start, int end) {
    mNumberPicker4.setRange(start, end);

}

public void setRange5(int start, int end) {
    mNumberPicker5.setRange(start, end);

}    

public void setRange6(int start, int end) {
    mNumberPicker6.setRange(start, end);

}

/**
 * Set the wrap option for the number picker
 * @param wrap true if values need to wrap
 * @deprecated Instead this can be set by retrieving the numberpicker
 * and setting the value directly.
 */

/**
 * Set the range for the number picker and the values to display
 * @param start the minimum allowed value
 * @param end the maximum allowed value
 * @param displayedValues values to display in the numberpicker instead of
 * the integer values of the range
 * @deprecated Instead this can be set by retrieving the numberpicker
 * and setting the value directly.
 */

public void setOnNumberSetListener(OnNumberSetListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {       
    if(which == BUTTON_POSITIVE){
         n1 = mNumberPicker1.getCurrent();
         n2 = mNumberPicker2.getCurrent();
         n3 = mNumberPicker3.getCurrent();
         n4 = mNumberPicker4.getCurrent();
         n5 = mNumberPicker5.getCurrent();
         n6 = mNumberPicker6.getCurrent(); 

         Button btHodometro = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btHodometroAbastecimento);
         btHodometro.setText(""+n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6);
    }  

}

public interface OnNumberSetListener {
    public void onNumberSet(int selectedNumber);    

}   


public int getN1() {
    return n1;
}

public int getN2() {
    return n2;
}

public int getN3() {
    return n3;
}

public int getN4() {
    return n4;
}

public int getN5() {
    return n5;
}

public int getN6() {
    return n6;
}
```

}

The problem is that when I try to set the text's buttom (bt.setText()) it give me a error.

```
11-22 15:36:44.489: E/AndroidRuntime(6733): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 15:36:44.489: E/AndroidRuntime(6733): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-22 15:36:44.489: E/AndroidRuntime(6733):     at br.com.going2.carrorama.helper.NumberPickerDialog.onClick(NumberPickerDialog.java:146)
11-22 15:36:44.489: E/AndroidRuntime(6733):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:165)
11-22 15:36:44.489: E/AndroidRuntime(6733):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-22 15:36:44.489: E/AndroidRuntime(6733):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-22 15:36:44.489: E/AndroidRuntime(6733):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-22 15:36:44.489: E/AndroidRuntime(6733):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 15:36:44.489: E/AndroidRuntime(6733):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-22 15:36:44.489: E/AndroidRuntime(6733):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
11-22 15:36:44.489: E/AndroidRuntime(6733):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
11-22 15:36:44.489: E/AndroidRuntime(6733):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont know what line in your code is `146` I am going to guess that this right here is your problem.

```
Button btHodometro = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btHodometroAbastecimento);
     btHodometro.setText(""+n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6);
```

`btHodometro` is null because it cannot find it in your view, you either dont have it in your view or you are not giving it the right view to use.

if this button is in your `R.layout.sixnumber` layout then you should initialize it in your constructor like you do the other elements

Comment: Is right at this line the error. This button is in my activity, when I click it, this Dialog appears and call the R.layout.sixnumber as Layout. Why is it crashing whren I call the Button? It is in my activity.

Comment: its crashing because you activity is no in view anymore if a dialog is up you need to create a callback to the activity when the dialog is closed to set the button

Comment: For one you should be using fragments and then you can do it like this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity